# Automapper ProjectTo not working with EFCore in memory database (unit tests)

Tags: .net-core, automapper, xunit

We are using Automappers ProjectTo method to build a DTO object that is a subset of a larger database view. It is working as expected when running the actual application but we have had a problem where it doesn't give expected results when unit testing with an EF Core In-Memory database. It seems to just be giving back 0 results no matter what the query. Here is the test I am trying to run.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetTemplateAdHocReportList_ReturnsOnlyTemplateReports()
{
    await TestHelper.SeedFull(ReportContext); // Calls SeedAdHocReports below along with other seed methods

    var results = await _sut.GetTemplateAdHocReports();

    results.Where(x => !x.IsTemplate).Count().Should().Be(0);
}
```

This is the Seed Data:

```
public static async Task SeedAdHocReports(ReportContext context)
{
    var reports = new AdHocReport[]
    {
        new AdHocReport()
        {
            Id = 1,
                Name = "DevExtreme Example Report",
                IsTemplate = true,
                AdHocDataSourceId = 1,
                Fields = "[{\"caption\":\"Category\",\"dataField\":\"ProductCategoryName\",\"expanded\":true,\"area\":\"row\"},{\"caption\":\"Subcategory\",\"dataField\":\"ProductSubcategoryName\",\"area\":\"row\"},{\"caption\":\"Product\",\"dataField\":\"ProductName\",\"area\":\"row\"},{\"caption\":\"Date\",\"dataField\":\"DateKey\",\"dataType\":\"date\",\"area\":\"column\"},{\"caption\":\"Amount\",\"dataField\":\"SalesAmount\",\"summaryType\":\"sum\",\"format\":{\"type\":\"currency\",\"precision\":2,\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"area\":\"data\"},{\"caption\":\"Store\",\"dataField\":\"StoreName\"},{\"caption\":\"Quantity\",\"dataField\":\"SalesQuantity\",\"summaryType\":\"sum\"},{\"caption\":\"Unit Price\",\"dataField\":\"UnitPrice\",\"format\":\"currency\",\"summaryType\":\"sum\"},{\"dataField\":\"Id\",\"visible\":false}]",
                Status = true
        }
    };

    context.AdHocReports.AddRange(reports);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Here is the GetTemplateAdHocReports method being tested

```
public async Task<IList<AdHocReportDto>> GetTemplateAdHocReports()
{
    //This gives the expected 1 object in the unit tests:
    var test = await _reportContext.AdHocReports.Where(x => x.Status && x.IsTemplate).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToListAsync();

    //This always comes back with a count of 0 even though the seed data should return 1 result
    var results = await _reportContext.AdHocReports.Where(x => x.Status && x.IsTemplate).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ProjectTo<AdHocReportDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider).ToListAsync();
    return results;
}
```

Finally in case they are useful here are the constructors:

```
public AdHocServiceTests()
{
    TestHelper = new TestHelper();

    var reportOptions = TestHelper.GetMockedReportDbOptions();
    ReportContext = new ReportContext(reportOptions);

    _sut = new AdHocService(ReportContext, TestHelper.Mapper, TestHelper.GetMockedNiceService().Object);
}

public TestHelper()
{
    var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<ReportDtoMapperProfile>();
    });
    Mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper(); // public property on TestHelper
}

public AdHocService(ReportContext reportContext, IMapper mapper, INiceService niceService)
{
    _niceService = niceService;
    _mapper = mapper;
    _reportContext = reportContext;
}
```

So the final question is why does the "var test = " line above work, but the following "var results =" line with the ProjectTo just keeps giving back 0 results?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: Is there a plugin to do this in VSCode?

Comment: I got the expression's debug view string from the link you posted. I wasn't able to use the plugin to make it easier to read but looking at it I think it is configured how I would expect and like I said it is working as expected in production, it is only the unit tests that don't work. Here is the generated expression: http://scratchpad.io/StackOverflow-Automapper-Issue

Comment: The debug view cannot help you to execute the query. Anyway, the most likely result is that the providers are handling it differently. There is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: How you check/know that query with projection returns no results?

Comment: Because when I debug the unit test the "var test" without the prejection gets back a list with 1 result as I would expect but the "var results" with the projection does not. It comes back with an empty list every time.

Comment: I have this problem too. Have you solved it?

Comment: I'm also experiencing a similar issue. Have you managed to get to the bottom of it?

Comment: Any update in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this too.

Your problem is most likely in `ReportDtoMapperProfile` class (you not showing this to us)
I assume your auto-mapper profile is linking the table to a child table for this property: `AdHocDataSourceId = 1`,

Because you forgot to seed the `AdHockDataSource` table, auto mapper returns no mapped results.